# PyQt5 QFileDialog does not work with pywinauto import

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pywinauto

Not sure if this is a bug or what, but its driving me crazy. Im using Python 3.5.4 32bit on Win 7.  **PyQt5's filefinder will not work if pywinauto is imported** to the script.  If someone could check if this script works for them (test the File>Import button):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
#import pywinauto

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)

        import_folder = QtWidgets.QAction("import", self)
        import_folder.triggered.connect(self.open_folder)

        main_menu = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = main_menu.addMenu("&File")
        fileMenu.addAction(import_folder)

        self.show()

    def open_folder(self):
        folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open folder")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And after running that, try uncommenting the pywinauto import and running the script again- it does not work for me.  Pywinauto is breaking my file explorer, but I need it in my program! There are no errors or anything, the app just freezes and does not respond. Idk what is going on.  If anyone could test this out that would be great.  If you have any guidance, cheers.

Comment: i get some `ModuleNotFoundError`s from the init of `pywinauto`, so it's not even starting for me.

Comment: Hmm... Order of imports might be the reason. It works this way: [py_inspect.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect/blob/master/py_inspect.py).

Comment: I tried changing the order of imports but it didn't help.  That code does not use the QFileDialog widget

Answer (score 3):

We could figure out the problem is inside PyQt because it always tries to use single threaded mode (STA) while `import pywinauto` already initialized COM with multi threaded mode (MTA). The workaround is:

```
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 2 # STA
import pywinauto
```

It could produce this warning (it's OK):

```
UserWarning: Apply externally defined coinit_flags: 2 
.format(module_sys.coinit_flags), UserWarning)
```